# Deploying a Cloud Service to multiple virtual networks

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network

I have an Azure cloud service hosted at example.cloudapp.net and within the portal I have configured two virtual networks one that is linked to a disaster recovery site and one that is linked to the main site.

I was successfully able to deploy the cloud service to within the virtual network by using the following configuration in the ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg:

```
<NetworkConfiguration>
<VirtualNetworkSite name="VNET1" />
<AddressAssignments>
  <InstanceAddress roleName="mybudget">
    <Subnets>
      <Subnet name="CloudService" />
    </Subnets>
  </InstanceAddress>
  <ReservedIPs>
    <ReservedIP name="mycloudservice" />
  </ReservedIPs>
</AddressAssignments>
```

I want to deploy the Cloud Service not only to VNET1 but also to VNET2, is there any way of deploying to additional VNETs at the same time? The subnets are named the same although have different values. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No, the same cloud service cannot be deployed to two different VNets. You can create a replica of the cloud service by using the same configuration files but in a new cloud service.